# Get ID value instead of the name in django-tables2

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I am new in django and I have some questions.

I have an html table rendered with django-tables2, this table is based on a model:
tables.py

```
class MasterTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = Master
```

I have a JS script to insert a dropdown button in the first column:

```
<script language="javascript">
function GetAllValues() {
    var tbl = document.getElementById("myTable");
    for (var i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++){
       for (var i = 1; i < tbl.rows.length; i++){
           tbl.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML = '<div class="btn-group">\
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">'
                                + tbl.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML +
                            '<span class="caret"></span>\
                            </button>\
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">\
                                <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#" >Configura</a>\
                                </li>\
                                <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#">Cambiar estado</a>\
                                </li>\
                                <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#">Ver estadíicas</a>\
                                </li>\
                                <li class="divider"></li>\
                                <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target"#">Reproceso</a>\
                                </li>\
                            </ul>\
                        </div>'
       } 
}    
</script>
```

In my models.py I have this

```
class Provider(models.Model):
    id_provider = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'mpc_proveedores'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Master(models.Model):
    id_provider = Models.ForeignKey(Provider,
                                    db_column='id_provider',
                                    primary_key=True,
                                    verbose_name='Provider')
    year = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    month = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'mpc_master'
```

the table I rendered in the html table is the model Master.
When I rendered the master model in the html table show me the provider name instead of the id_provider and that it's fine, but I need to get the value of the id_provider when I click in the first column of my html table, instead of the name of the provider.

How can I get the value of the id_provider instead of the provider name and after pass the id_provider as parameter to another page(form).

Any advice, link or snippet will be very very appreciated

thanks in advance

Comment: I haven't used django-tables2, but you should be able to get the id_provider something like this: `Master.id_provider_id` or `Master.id_provider.id_provider`

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do like this:

```
class MasterTable(tables.Table):

    def render_id_provider(self, **kwargs):
        return kwargs['value'].id_provider
    class Meta:
        model = Master
```

Comment: Thanks Ruddra, there's only one problem in my hmtl page where I show the table is displayed the value instead the name of the provider. Now I can get the what I need, but the table don't look good with a number in the place of the provider name.

Comment: well, you can provide both name and id in tables if you use: `return str(kwargs['value'].id_provider) + ' ' +  kwargs['value'].name` instead of `return kwargs['value'].id_provider`

Comment: Thanks for the quickly reply. I try what you write me, but the modificaction won't resolve the issue. I will keep searching and if i find something i will tell you